# not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I tried uninstalling [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) but now am getting no filetype detection. With this issue I get no filetype detection and thus no syntax support. Starting vim via `vim -V1` I get the following message:

```
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"
```

I have spent more time than I'd like already trying to fix this issue, but haven't found anything to help. I wouldn't think pathogen could have crippled file detection this badly. Has anyone had this issue or know how to fix it?

Comment: Pathogen certainly didn't cripple anything. Do you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your `~/.vimrc`? Is it before or after the two pathogen lines? Could you post your `~/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

Your key to solving this problem is the information in `:set runtimepath?` Your `ftdetect` directory must be below any of the listed locations, typically the first, `~/.vim/`. Check whether there's still something in your `~/.vimrc` that modifies the `'runtimepath'` setting.

Pathogen installs all plugins in separate `bundle/` subdirectories; you need to move those subtrees back into the single consolidated directory to make them work again.

Comment: I never installed `ftdetect` as a bundle. Isn't that a default vim plugin? My current `runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/local/share/vim/vim73,/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after`

Comment: No, `ftdetect` is not a default directory.

Comment: `ftdetect` is a default subdirectory of the runtimepath (like `autoload`, `ftplugin`, `plugin`, etc.) It is not a plugin, but a special location with particular semantics. Vim does not ship with any `ftdetect` scripts (is that what you mean, @romainl?), but you may have installed some (in `bundle/<bundlename>/ftdetect/<scriptname>.vim`)

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.